# Python no module named error

Tags: python

```
tree
 systemMonitoring
├── ddos_logging_service.py
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
├── systemMonitor
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── monitor.py
│   └── source.py
└── systemMonitor.service
```

Its my python program file hierarchy...
I created `systemMonitor` directory on my python program to seperate `setup.py` and service file from others. After separation,when I try to run monitor.py  I'm getting this error:

```
    File "monitor.py", line 3, in <module>
    from systemMonitor import source  
    ImportError: No module named 'systemMonitor'
```

begining `monitor.py` is:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
import time,psutil
from systemMonitor import source
```

Answer (score 1):

In `systemMonitor/monitor.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time,psutil
from . import source
```

Check this: https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html

Comment: not worked
   File "systemMonitor/monitor.py", line 3, in <module>
   from . import source
 SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Comment: @pala9323 How did you run the program? By `python monitor.py`?

Comment: python3 monitor.py

Comment: @pala9323 Then just `import source`.